# Консоль показывает разную длину одного массива в разных местах

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как это возможно и как от этого избавиться? Использую состояние React[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для другого массива, распечатанного одновременно с этим то же самое. Но при еще одной итерации распечатки длина становится правильной, но вылезают какие-то странные баги при работе с массивами. Что это такое?

Comment: там может быть проблема если длина меняется то `log` будет показывать его не корректно.Вы лучше смотрите длину массива в `console.table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

У нас есть такой код:

```
const arr = [3,2,4];

console.log(arr); // (3) [3, 2, 4]

arr.push(31);

console.log(arr); //(4) [3, 2, 4, 31]
```

В первом логе консоль показывает массив с длиной в три элемента.Но если нажать на стрелочку чтобы раскрыть его полностью увидим такой результат

```
0: 3
1: 2
2: 4
3: 31
length: 4
```

Длина массива 4 элемента хотя мы еще не добавили 4-й элемент.Второй log будет показывать соответственно точно такой же результат.

Для того чтобы решить эту проблему используйте `console.table`.`Table` будет показывать красивую таблицу с правильными результатами.

```
(index)   Value
  0         3
  1         2
  2         4
```

Comment: Несколько вопросов:
1. Все эти операции синхронные - почему первый лог будет писать массив, который получился в результате последующих операций?
2. Значит ли это, что при log консоль ссылается на конкретное место в памяти, где лежит массив, а table копирует к себе то, что конкретно в этот момент там находится, и поэтому содержимое не изменяется?

Comment: @Enkei отвечаю:Не имеет значение синхронные ваши операции или нет так происходит потому что это копия одного и того же массива.То есть лог показывает одного массива.Если вы напишете вот так `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));` то не будет такого результата потому что такой подход удаляет ссылку на основной объект.Надеюсь я ответил на оба  вопроса одним ответом